# Symfony classNotFoundInNamespaces exception

Tags: symfony, rss

I am working with a bundle called [rss-atom-bundle](https://github.com/alexdebril/rss-atom-bundle). Through this bundle I should be able to fetch the RSS feeds and save them to the database.

I can get the bundle to work up till getting the feeds from the URL but when I try to `presist` I get the following error and I just cant figure it out why I am getting it.

```
The class 'Debril\RssAtomBundle\Protocol\Parser\Item' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Entity, AppBundle\Entity`
```

Looking online and at stackoverflow i came across questions that were related to this but all of them are talking about by default the `Entity` should be inside the Entity folder of the Bundle and if they are not then this error appears but my Entity files are inside Entity folder and I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/alexdebril/rss-atom-bundle/wiki/Reading-feeds) given by the bundle author but still i cant get passed this error

This is what my `Controller` looks like

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // fetch the FeedReader
        $reader = $this->container->get('debril.reader');

        // this date is used to fetch only the latest items
        $unmodifiedSince = '01/01/2000';
        $date = new \DateTime($unmodifiedSince);

        // the feed you want to read
        $url = 'http://example.com/feed/';

        $feeds = $reader->getFeedContent($url, $date);
        $items = $feeds->getItems();

        dump($items);
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $em->persist($item);
        }
        $em->flush();
```

As per bundle instructions I did implement `FeedInterface` to my `Feed` Entity and `ItemInInterface, ItemOutInterface` to my `Item` Entity

This is what my `orm.yml` looks like for Feed and Item Entity

**Feed**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Feed:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: 255
        description:
            type: text
        link:
            type: text
        publicId:
            type: text
        lastModified:
            type: datetime
        lastViewed:
            type: datetime
    oneToMany:
        items:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Item
            mappedBy: feed
            cascade: ["persist"]
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Item**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Item:
    type: entity
    table: null
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: 255
        title:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        summary:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        description:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        medias:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        updated:
            type: string
            nullable: true
        publicId:
            type: string
            nullable: true
        link:
            type: string
            nullable: true
        comment:
            type: string
            nullable: true
        author:
            type: string
            nullable: true
    manyToOne:
        feed:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Feed
            inversedBy: items
            joinColumn:
                name: feed_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Any help will be really appreciated as I am clueless why i am getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add RssAtomBundle to the list with mappings in app/config/config.yml

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
                AsseticBundle: ~
                RssAtomBundle: ~
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what is this supposed to do?